# laravel admin, upload image in ckeditor

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor, laravel-admin

I am using laravel admin which is installed with `"encore/laravel-admin" package: "*",`

Next I installed another package `"laravel-admin-ext/ckeditor": "*",`

It adds a `ckeditor` form to edit the field in the admin panel itself

His code with all the options that I added looks like this

```
$form->ckeditor('description', __('Description'))->required()->options(
    [
        'toolbarGroups' => [
            ['name' => 'clipboard', 'groups' => ['clipboard', 'spellchecker', 'source']],
            ['name' => 'undo'],
            ['name' => 'tools', 'groups' => ['tools']],
            ['name' => 'document', 'groups' => ['mode']],
            ['name' => 'maximize'],
            ['name' => 'source'],
            ['name' => 'basicstyles', 'groups' => ['basicstyles', 'cleanup', 'maximize']],
            ['name' => 'colors'],
            ['name' => 'paragraph', 'groups' => ['list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi']],
            ['name' => 'others', 'groups' => ['others', 'maximize']],
            ['name' => 'about', 'groups' => ['about']],
        ],
        'removeButtons' => '',
    ]
);
```

The question is, is it possible to include image loading in these options? And where will they be stored?

Comment: You are using a lot of relative and absolute positions, which makes it hard to see where the problem is. Relative and absolute positioning makes the elements "float above" the content, therefor it can overlap other elements. You'd better use the static position, but I can't make a good judgement of the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all the options you have set and you will be able to download files via a link

```
$form->ckeditor('description', __('Description'))->required()->options();
```